# How to find what id to use next in SQLite3 and Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I'm currently using Java and JDBC to work with SQLite. When inserting a new object into a database, how am I supposed to know which id to use or how to generate it?

Here's my code I'm using:

```
private void insertIntoTable() {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/test.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" +
                "VALUES (2 , 'Brian Brianson', 32, 'California', 60000.00);";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I'm inserting new items, how should I find out which id I should be using to insert into the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns automatically behave as auto increment columns, q.v. the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).  You need only insert `NULL` values for the ID column and SQLite will populate the value for you.  That is, use this code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" +
             "VALUES (null, 'Brian Brianson', 32, 'California', 60000.00);";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: Only issue is that looking at the SQLite documentation, it says this: "The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed." Should I be concerned about that?

Comment: @SirGoose Not if having the auto increment column makes your logic/life easier.  The feature is there for a reason, if you need it then use it.

Comment: @SirGoose - Read [that page](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) again. If your "ID" column is defined as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` then SQLite will automatically assign a value if you pass it a NULL (or, better yet, simply omit that column from the INSERT statement). The note you cited is specifically about the optional `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword, which specifies a slightly different algorithm to use when automatically assigning the ROWID value. (Tim: You may want to edit your answer to clarify that an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column will serve as an Identity (ROWID) column without `AUTOINCREMENT`.)

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for the note.  I had the right answer to another question, but I have updated now.